# How to Create Resources File For VB6 in C#

Tags: c#, vb6, resources

How to Create Resources File For VB6 in C#? I used ResXResourceWriter class and generated RES file but it's not for vb6. i researched and found Resources Editor For vb6. I tested and just I could add manifest but I want to add files. How Can I add files to resources for vb6?

Comment: It depends what you want the resource to contain. The version resource is controller by the project properties dialog in the VB6 IDE. String tables, cursor, bitmap, icon, or custom resources can also be edited in the VB6 IDE using the [Resource Editor Add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228672(v=vs.60).aspx) as described in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RC.EXE Windows utility to create Resource files (call it from C# using [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx))

[Using RC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381055(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: It's better to use the VB6 IDE to edit RC files for VB6